# Компилятор для C++

Tags: ide, c++

Помогите найти самый обычный текстовый компилятор для C++. У меня был Borland Visual C++ и другие (визуальные), а самоучитель, который у меня, рассчитан на текстовое редактирование исходного кода. Какой маленький текстовый и простой компилятор для обучения С++ посоветуете?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Текстовых компиляторов не бывает. В любом пакете визуальной среды присутствует обыкновенный компилятор. В любом случае, это отдельная программа, которая переламывает исходный код и дает машинный код, который воспринимает компьютер. И компилятор можно вызывать вручную. Параметры задаются через командную строчку. Просто в случае визуальных сред вызов компилятора скрыт и весь его вывод идет через визуальную среду.

К тому же Borland Visual C++ нет. Есть Borland C++, Borland/Inprise/Embarcadero C++ Builder и Microsoft Visual C++ (в составе MS Visual Studio). Это самые известные IDE для C/C++.

PS: если у Вас линукc - проще всего воспользоваться gcc/g++. Использовать очень просто:

> gcc source_file.c
>
> ./a.out

Comment: Для windows возьмите MinGW

Answer (score 0):

dev c++

Answer (score 0):

mingw?

Comment: туда же - cygwin?