# Компилятор для C++

Tags: c++

Какой вы мне посоветуете компилятор для C++?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/15482/208074

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/40572/208074

Answer (score 3):

Для Windows лучший вариант - это MSVC, который идет либо с Platform SDK, либо с Visual C++ Express. И то, и то свободно и бесплатно скачивается с сайта MS и устанавливается на Windows. Для новичка очень удобно: все на русском и подо все есть справка.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте IDE, например: MS Visual Studio, Code::Blocks, dev cpp.
А неплохие компиляторы это GCC и MINGW

Comment: code::block идет без компилятора.

Comment: угу, ошибся, code::block + GCC или mingw

Answer (score 0):

для виндоус-dev cpp
для линукс g++(он вроде и под виндоус есть, но я его не нашел)

Comment: есть конечно же, называется mingw

Answer (score 0):

> Какой вы мне посоветуете компилятор для C++?

Смотря для каких задач.

1. Под винду - Microsoft CL (C Language) Compiler. Есть в составе MS Visual Studio разных мастей и в составе Windows DDK (Driver Development Kit)
2. gcc/g++ - можно с его помощью писать переносимые м/у Windows и Linux приложения. Также присутствует поддержка множества аппаратных платформ. Имеется поддержка свежего стандарта C++0x
3. Intel C++ Compiler - для получения качественно оптимизированного кода (короче, скорость выполнения выше)
4. [Comeau C++ Compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) - говорят, что он лучше всего соответствует спецификации языка.

Answer (score 0):

Я вчера себе установил MINGW 4.6.1. Самую последнюю версию его. Полностью поддержка (хотя стоит проверить)нового стандарта C++11. Рекомендую воспользоваться вот этой ссылкой http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Там написано подробно как всё установить + еще и boost у вас будет

Answer (score -1):

А мне как-то [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) больше по душе, но это мое имхо.

Comment: это ide, а не компилятор:)