# Где найти компилятор для C++ и какой лучше?

Tags: компилятор, c++

Подскажите, где можно скачать программу компилятор для C++ и какая лучше? Хочется начать программировать, но не могу найти прогу!

Comment: ОС какая ?

Comment: * [Преимущества и недостатки компиляторов С/Си++ под разными ОС][1]
 * [Far как компилятор для C++][2]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/40044
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/23612

Comment: Начинает только программировать ,соответственно Винда xp/7 ,ставь Visual Studio ,или поищи на сайте подобные вопросы их куча)

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как с последними MS VC++, но у более ранних версий были проблемы совместимости со стандартом. Так что g++ из комплекта gcc (к тому же бесплатный и многоплатформенный). Гнездо: [link text](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/)
Под винды два основных варианта: gcc под cygwin (тогда надо ставить cygwin -- www.cygwin.com) или mingw (рекомендуется поставить ещё msys)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)
2. C++ Builder
3. dev C++

Это с ходу)) Компилятор выберешь сам по функционалу и удобности.

Answer (score 0):

Найти можно в интернете. 
Если ты на `Windows`, то это `C++ Builder`, `Dev C++`.
Если ты под `*nix`, то он должен у тебя уже быть.

```
user@device:~$ g++  
#если пишет, что приложение не найдено, то  
user@device:~$ sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: не думаю что автор под *nix т.к. такого вопроса скорее всего не было бы :)